# changing the href with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an image with an ID of 27.

I need to change the href of the link that surrounds it.  How do i do this with jquery?

Here is my link and image attribute.  Note. I cant set the id to the link.

```
<a href=""><img src="" id="27"></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#27").parent().attr("href", "somewhere.html");
```

This gets the direct parent of the element matched by the selector. Alternatively, you could use `closest`, which traverses the DOM tree until it finds a matching element, but I'm assuming that the `img` will always be a direct child of the `a` element.

Note, however, that `id` attribute values cannot start with a number unless you are using an HTML5 `doctype`.

**Update**

Having seen the split opinion in the many answers to this question on the use of `parent()` vs. `closest("a")`, I put a quick performance test together, and, in Chrome 12 at least, the `parent()` method is significantly faster (over 30% faster when I ran it).

Here's a [link to the test](http://jsperf.com/jqclosest-vs-parent).

Comment: The negligible performance difference is not a good enough reason to write brittle code in most situations.

Comment: @RSG - Agreed, but in this situation, the chances seem very high that the `img` will always be a direct child of the `a` element.

Comment: First, Jimmy, props for benchmarking the damn thing instead of just assuming that `parent` is faster.  But, according to your test, `parent` takes 24μs and `closest` takes 35μs, a difference of only **11μs**!  It would take **95,000** iterations for a one-second delay (on my doddering old Mac running an obsolete Firefox version -- a modern installation might be much faster).  @RSG is right.  But again, thanks for going the extra mile.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like:

`$('#27').closest('a').attr('href','newLink.html');`

Comment: +1 for using the more general `closest`, unlike all the rest of you nerds.

Comment: D'oh, and now @RSG is biting on you.

Comment: @Malvolio - More general, yes, but also slower :) See update to my answer. Not that it will make any difference in the real world!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `parent` selector with the `attr` method.

```
$('#27').parent().attr('href', someNewValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Has any one considered

```
$("#27").parent().attr("href", "something.html");
```

Because that would work.

Answer (score 0):

James answer is good.

I prefer to use `closest` instead of `parent` in case the design changes.

```
$("#27").closest("a").attr("href","infinityandbeyond.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $mylink="test_link.html";
$('#27').parent().attr('href',$mylink);
```